# JavaScript - Filter array with mutation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to filter a array by keeping the same array without creating a new one.

with `Array.filter()` :

```
getFiltersConfig() {
  return this.config.filter((topLevelConfig) => topLevelConfig.name !== 'origin')
}
```

what is the best way to get the same result by filtering by value without returning a new array ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, what's the use case?

Comment: Filter creates by definition a new array matching your creteria.

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to `filter` and then `splice`.

Comment: @Nit @ihkwiss I want to keep the same array, like with `Array.splice()`

Comment: I have a specific use case for this. I need to loop through an array of values, and remove the corresponding values from another array. I obviously can't create a new array for each loop, and I need to remove by value rather than index.

Keith's answer below seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Not sure why would you want to do mutation but if you really want to do it, maybe assign it back to itself?

```js
let arr = ['a','b','a'];

arr = arr.filter(x => x !== 'a');

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri  For future reference, remember this is not mutating the array, it's creating a new one.

Comment: Yeah. This is NOT what they asked for. Sure it is in the same variable, but it is a new array.

Comment: @Keith what can go wrong if I create a new one while using the same variable?

Comment: @Ooker Nothing!, but it's not mutating the array like the OP asked for.  Maybe the OP miss understood what mutating means as this became the accepted answer.  But based on the the title is totally incorrect and might explain the down-votes.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, I thought it might make sense to show a mutated array variant.

Below is a snippet with a simple function `mutationFilter`, this will filter the array directly, notice in this function the loop goes in reverse, this is a technique for deleting items with a mutated array.

Also a couple of tests to show how `Array.filter` creates a new array, and `mutationFilter` does not.

Although in most cases creating a new array with `Array.filter` is normally what you want.  One advantage of using a mutated array, is that you can pass the array by reference, without you would need to wrap the array inside another object.  Another advantage of course is memory, if your array was huge, inline filtering would take less memory.

```js
let arr = ['a','b','a'];
let ref = arr; //keep reference of original arr

function mutationFilter(arr, cb) {
  for (let l = arr.length - 1; l >= 0; l -= 1) {
    if (!cb(arr[l])) arr.splice(l, 1);
  }
}

const cond = x => x !== 'a';

const filtered = arr.filter(cond);
mutationFilter(arr, cond);

console.log(`ref === array -> ${ref === arr}`);
console.log(arr);

console.log(`ref === filtered -> ${ref === filtered}`);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, but I'm confused by the sample code. Why would ref === arr? ref still contains three elements, and arr only one.

Comment: @RobertM.  Late reply here, both `ref` & `arr` will contain only 1, that's the side effect mutation will have, and is often the reason of confusion and is the reason it usually advised against.

Comment: Oh, I see, ref contains the same number of elements as arr because it's a *reference* to the original array. I was missing that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to filter a array by keeping the same array without creating a new one.

> what is the best way to get the same result by filtering by value without returning a new array ?

I have an answer for the second criterion, but violates the first. I suspect that you may want to "not create a new one" specifically because you only want to preserve the reference to the array, not because you *don't want to create a new array*, necessarily (e.g. for memory concerns).

What you could do is create a temp array of what you want

```
var temp = this.config.filter((topLevelConfig) => topLevelConfig.name !== 'origin')
```

Then set the length of the original array to 0 and push.apply() the values "in-place"

```
this.config.length = 0; //clears the array
this.config.push.apply(this.config, temp); //adds what you want to the array of the same reference
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, for a particular use case. I wish the OP had been more specific about why he wanted this.

Answer (score -1):

You could define you custom method like so:

```js
if(!Array.prototype.filterThis){
  Array.prototype.filterThis = function (callBack){
          if(typeof callBack !== 'function')
              throw new TypeError('Argument must of type <function>');
    let t = [...this];
    this.length = 0;
    for(let e of t) if(callBack(e)) this.push(e);
          return this;
  }
}

let a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,1,5];
a.filterThis(x=>x!=5);
console.log(a);
```

> Warning: Be very cautious in altering built in prototypes. I would even say unless your making a polyfill don't touch. The errors it can cause can be very subtle and very hard to debug.

Comment: Be very cautious in altering built in prototypes.   I would even say unless your making a polyfill don't touch.  The errors it can cause can be very subtle and very hard to debug.

Comment: @Keith, I did not overwrite any built-ins. I made a new method.

Comment: No you altered the prototype of the built-in Array..  For more details about why -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: @Keith. Yeah got your point. Basically since it's not standard method. A method with this name might later be added by ES Spec and then it would cause problems right?

Comment: Yeah, you never know ES Spec one day may add a `filterThis` method :)  It's happened before, apparently MooTools added a contains method to the prototype, and actually conflicted with ES6 contains causing no end of trouble.

Comment: Hmmn.. I'm just gonna a add a check for `filterThis` in my code if it already Exists or not and add a warning Text below with your comment. I'm not gonna remove the answer though. This will remind me next time when I try to alter built-in prototypes. :D